# mySQL check for column

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to check for the existence of a column using the syntax
`SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "my_table" AND COLUMN_NAME = "my_column"`

Is there a way to check for the existence of a column when the DB user doesn't have access to the information_schema? Or would you just do something like try a SELECT from that column and if you get an error then you know that the column doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good old `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name`:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-columns.html